# Slice image in dynamic number of squares (grid) and save corner coordinates of those squares in list

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm reading in an image with the Pillow library in Python. I want to "slice" it into squares, and save the corner coordinates of each of the squares in a list. For example in the image below, I would like to save the corner coordinates for square 15. (Top left corner is 0,0)

[image: slices]

The first think I do after reading in the image is calculate the modulus of the height and width in pixels by the number of slices, and crop the image so the resulting number of pixels per square is the same and an integer.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
fileName = 'eyeImg_86.png'
img = Image.open(fileName)

vertical_slices = 8
horizontal_slices = 4

height = img.height
width = img.width

new_height = height - (height % horizontal_slices)
new_width = width - (width %  vertical_slices)

img = img.crop((0, 0, new_width, new_height))
```

Then I calculate the size in pixels of each vertical and horizontal step.

```
horizontal_step = int(new_width / vertical_slices)
vertical_step = int(new_height / horizontal_slices)
```

And then I loop over the ranges between 0 to the total number of vertical and horizontal slices and append to a nested list (each inner list is a row)

```
points = []
for i in range(horizontal_slices+1):
    row = []
    for j in range(vertical_slices+1):
        row.append((horizontal_step*j, vertical_step*i))
    points.append(row)
```

Here's where I'm struggling to draw and to calculate what I need inside each of these squares. If I try to loop over all those points and draw them on the image.

```
with Image.open(fileName) as im: 
    im = im.convert(mode='RGB')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    for i in range(horizontal_slices+1):
        if i < horizontal_slices:
            for j in range(vertical_slices+1):
                if j < vertical_slices:
                    draw.line([points[i][j], points[i+1][j-1]], fill=9999999)
```

[image: slices2]

Is there an easy way that I can dynamically give it the rows and columns and save each of the square coordinates to a list of tuples for example?

I'd like to both be able to draw them on top of the original image, and also calculate the number of black pixels inside each of the squares.

EDIT: To add some clarification, since the number of rows and columns of the grid is arbitrary, it will likely not be made of squares but rectangles. Furthermore, the numbering of these rectangles should be done row-wise from left to right, like reading.

Thank you

Comment: Just a nitpick: if I'm not mistaken, and if the number of horizontal and vertical slices are chosen arbitrarily, you'll get rectangles, not squares. Of course this doesn't change the problematic.

Comment: Another point: for clarity, how do you want to label your squares ? By their number from 1 to h_slices*v_slices (15 in your example) for by coordinates (for example, your square 15 could be column 5, row 2, or col 4 row 1 if you count from 0) ?

Comment: Very valid point haha, yeah it would be mostly rectangles. I'm thinking of numbering them in the same order as you would read a book. For example first row would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 second row, 9,10,11... etc.

Comment: Ok; please edit your question to clarify that; I'm working on it; I noticed in your points creation block that you seem to have swapped i and j (if I understand correctly, points is a list of upper-left coordinates of your rectangles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were (from my understanding) inconsistencies in your use of "horizontal/vertical"; I also removed the points list, since you can easily convert the rectangle number to its upper-left corner coords (see the function in the end); I draw the grid directly by drawing all horizontal lines and all vertical lines).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
fileName = 'test.png'
img = Image.open(fileName)

vertical_slices = 8
horizontal_slices = 6

height = img.height
width = img.width

new_height = height - (height % vertical_slices)
new_width = width - (width %  horizontal_slices)

img = img.crop((0, 0, new_width, new_height))

horizontal_step = int(new_width / horizontal_slices)
vertical_step = int(new_height / vertical_slices)

# drawing the grid

img = img.convert(mode='RGB')
pix = img.load()

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
for i in range(horizontal_slices+1):
    draw.line([(i*horizontal_step,0), (i*horizontal_step,new_height)], fill=9999999)
for j in range(vertical_slices+1):
      draw.line([(0,j*vertical_step), (new_width,j*vertical_step)], fill=9999999)
      
# with rectangles being numbered from 1 (upper left) to v_slices*h_slices (lower right) in reading order

def num_to_ul_corner_coords(num):
    i = (num-1)%horizontal_slices
    j = (num-1)//horizontal_slices
    return(i*horizontal_step,j*vertical_step)
```

This should do what you want, provided your picture is pure black and white:

```
def count_black_pixels(num) :
    cnt = 0
    x, y = num_to_ul_corner_coords(num)
    for i in range(horizontal_step):
        for j in range(vertical_step):
            if pix[x+i,y+j] == (0,0,0):
                cnt += 1

    perc = round(cnt/(horizontal_step*vertical_step)*100,2)

    return cnt, perc
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Wow, thank you. I've been banging my head for a while. Just one quick question, I want to get the percent of black pixels in each rectangle. The total pixels per rectangle is equal to horizontal_step * vertical_step, correct?

Comment: Lastly one more question, is there an easy way to get the center point coordinates of each of the squares? I'm thinking based on their index to add up to the previous index and then half of the current one?

Comment: Nevermind, I can do the coordinates of the top left corner plus half of both steps

Comment: Indeed, tha't's the simplest way :)